# Exclude specific email address from form submissions

Tags: email, block, spam-prevention

I am totally new to PHP and I am just trying to block spam in my forms. I have
figured out how to do a honeypot (url field) with the following code that
blocks 90% of the spam - but this one irritating emailer gets through
(let's call them `redacted@example.com`). I would like to write one line of
code in my form that just says if the email field is filled out with the text
`'redacted@example.com'`, then don't pass the form through. Is there anyone who can help me do this?

```
// if the url field is empty
// if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){

// then send the form to your email
// mail( 'myemail@me.com', 'Contact Form', print_r($_POST,true) );
// }

// otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == '') {
    if ($_POST['email'] != 'dukang2004@yahoo.com') {
        // then send the form to your email
         mail( 'myemail@me.com', 'Contact Form', print_r($_POST,true) );
    }
}
```

Comment: If it works for you, then do accept the answer so that it doesn't show up under unanswered answer.

Comment: it works!! I feel silly asking...this is the first time I've ever posted in this forum. How do I accept the answer?